# Content URI of Camera Images *Only*

Tags: android, camera, uri

I'm using a ContentObserver to detect when a user takes a photo. Further, I need to actually grab the photo once the photo is taken.

Right now I'm using the URI MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI to detect a change and to grab the images.

However, I've noticed that I'm also grabbing images from third-party, non-camera applications that seem to save photos to external storage.

How can I grab camera images only?

If it's impossible to know the URIs for arbitrary camera applications, is it possible to at least get a URI for the stock Android camera?

Comment: usually camera app saves at DCIM/Camera , so you could check the path. But if third party apps save to DCIM/Camera folder its not good

Answer (score 0):

Remember that Android Camera usually (99.999999% of the time) stores photon on DCIM directory, so, you can filter for DCIM in your cursor.